# Can I enable bracket matching in nano?

Tags: nano, syntax

```
else if( d && ( (d <= b && d <= s) || (!b && !s) )   smallest = d
```

Consider this piece of code of C++. Can we have bracket matching (highlighting opening bracket when cursor on closing bracket & vice versa)?

Comment: did you mean `set matchbrackets ` in nanorc?

Comment: yup thanks for hint, I just figured out this and posted answer. Thanks for help

Comment: `Nano` uses regex for highlighting, which, I believe, cannot give such a smart color picking.

Answer (score 10):

```
set brackets ""')>]}"
set matchbrackets "(<[{)>]}"
```

Update `~/.nanorc` (or perhaps `/etc/nanorc`) with these lines and it works like a charm.

When on any bracket press <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> (often this will be <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>) and there you go to the other paired bracket.